# How to use slopes (3 points are given) to prove that they form a right triangle?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Question: Use slopes to show that $A(-3, -1)$, $B(3, 3)$ and $C(-9, 8)$ are vertices of a right triangle.

My try at the problem: I know that we can find the slopes of $AB$, $BC$ and $CA$ and then prove that the slope of one line is the negative reciprocal of another and hence, two lines are perpendicular. However, it can be the case that two of the lines are perpendicular, but the other one is not perpendicular/parallel to either of them as follows:

[image: the image]

In these case, we do see two lines perpendicular to each other, but no right triangle. How to we actually solve the problem them?

Comment: I do not understand the objection. If two slopes are negative reciprocals, then the three points form a right triangle. The third line will not bw parallel/perpendicular to the two perpendicular lines. In our case the triangle is right-angled at $A$.

Comment: Ok. I think I got it. It's not just that slopes of lines are given. There are those points given which meet at the same point. Hence, while we are using the concept of slopes, it's not that the lines are coming from infinity, there are those points which are common. Correct?

Comment: Yes, we are dealing with $3$ specific points. It is certainly true that we can find lines $l_1$, l_2,l_3$ such that the first two lines are orthogonal but the three lines do not form a right triangle, because of parallelism or because $l_3$ goes through the meeting point of the first three lines. Though we could call that a degenerate right-angled triangle. But here we are starting with points. Nothing much can go wrong, except that some slope may not exist because one of the sides is parallel to the $y$-axis.

Comment: Sorry, TeX error, now I cannot erase. With three points, nothing much can go wrong, though we may have to deal with the special case where a line segment is parallel to the $y$-axis.

Comment: ok? @ Andre Nicolas: We can certainly find lines $l_1,l_2,l_3$ such that the first two lines are orthogonal but the three lines do not form a right triangle, because of parallelism or because $l_3$ goes through the meeting point of the first three lines. Though we could call that a degenerate right-angled triangle. But here we are starting with points. Nothing much can go wrong, except that some slope may not exist because one of the sides is parallel to the axis.

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is that *you are given three distinct points*. Constructing three lines from those points cannot result in the diagram you give in your concern. You have two possible outcomes:

1. The three points are colinear, so all slopes will have the same value = no right angle (also demonstrated by the lack of any two being negative reciprocals).
2. The three points form a triangle and can be tested as you describe. There is also the special case of zero/infinite slope combinations that needs to be tested separately (eg. $\{(0,0),(4,3),(4,0)\}$), which your "concern diagram" also happens to contain.

Answer (score 0):

There are three angles and three pairs of adjacent lines in a triangle.

Calculate slope product pairs $(m_1m_2, m_2m_3, m_3m_1)$ and one among them should be equal to $-1$... that is sufficient to locate the vertex making the right angle.

Answer (score -1):

There are actually two process where we can show its a right triangle

1. By showing that any two of those line's slope are perpendicular.
   Actually Its a right triangle so basically multiplying the slope of the hypotenuse wont get the result with either of the lines. We have to find out all the slopes of those lines and multiply all of them simultaneously.
   Given, A(−3,−1), B(3,3) and C(−9,8)
   Slope=(difference of y/difference of x)
   Slope of AB=2/3,
   Slope of AC=-3/2,
   Slope of BC=-5/12
   Now we have to multiply any two of them two find out whether they are perpendicular or not
   By using my intuitive, I could spot it and it should be AB x AC=-1
   If you are still unable to reckon that you can try all of them
   You can do all of them AB x BC, BC x AC.
2. Another method is calculating the distance between those points and find out the length then use the Pythagorean theorem
   Thanks for asking